# Can a memory leak cause only OutOfMemoryError in Java?

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, java-8

I have [this memory issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104516/java-8-with-jetty-on-linux-memory-issue) with Java 8 on Jetty Server. After exploring about memory leaks, it is not clear for me that: whether a Java Memory leak will cause just jvm OutOfMemoryError only? or can cause excessive physical memory usage(which can't be tracked by profiler) resulting a system crash?

Answer (score 2):

A memory leak can lead to any resource being exhausted.

A common one is running out of file descriptors, i.e. files or keeping unused sockets alive.  This limit can be as low as 1024.

It would be possible to do the same thing with GUI components or any component which proxies an external resource.